# How to generate keywords for documents stored in MarkLogic?

Tags: keyword, marklogic

I need to generate a list of keywords for each document in a set of documents that are loaded into MarkLogic.  I am considering running cts:distinctive-terms against the set of documents, but cannot figure out how to get a list of keywords for each document rather than a list of terms relevant to the set.  Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were you using the `score=logtf` option? When I tried that, the scores of stop-words went up quite a bit. If you think about it this makes sense: the database can no longer use IDF to weed them out. If you only want TF, though, you could filter using a stop-word list - as already suggested.

But `logtfidf` scoring should naturally penalize stop-words. You can set the `min-val` option or other options to tune the results. For example, here I set `min-val` to 27 because stop-words began to appear at 26. The right options will depend on the existing database content, because of IDF.

```
cts:distinctive-terms(
  text { 'I need to generate a list of keywords for each document in a set of documents that are loaded into MarkLogic. I am considering running cts:distinctive-terms against the set of documents, but cannot figure out how to get a list of keywords for each document rather than a list of terms relevant to the set. Can anyone suggest a solution?' },
  <options xmlns="cts:distinctive-terms"
   xmlns:db="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database">
    <min-val>27</min-val>
    <use-db-config>false</use-db-config>
    <db:stemmed-searches>true</db:stemmed-searches>
    <db:word-searches>false</db:word-searches>
    <db:fast-phrase-searches>false</db:fast-phrase-searches>
  </options>)/cts:term/cts:word-query/cts:text/string()
=>
load
set
solution
term
document
list
keyword
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not passing an options node. This works great even if I remove the min-val option. It returns 0 to 10 terms for each document. What affects the number of terms returned? I'm mostly concerned with the cases in which 0 are returned.

Comment: `max-terms` - from http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/SearchBuiltins.xml&category=SearchBuiltins&function=cts:distinctive-terms - but if you see 0 then something is odd. Can you reproduce it with a standalone text node, like I used above?

Answer (score 3):

Simply iterate over the docs of interest and call cts:distinct-terms for each doc separately:

```
for $doc in doc()
return
    cts:distinctive-terms($doc)
```

HTH!

Comment: That is what I tried at first, but ended up getting "the", "is", and other equally uninteresting words as the majority of terms returned.  It was suggested that I should run cts:distinctive-terms against the entire set of documents.  This returned a much better set of terms, but I couldn't figure out where to go from there.

Comment: @joe-glorioso That is actually a slightly different question. Run distinctive terms against a large set of documents (if not simply all), take the top terms of those and treat those as a stop words list. Filtering them away from smaller sets, or single documents. I have done some similar tricks myself recently..